# How to make Alt+Shift/Ctrl+Shift switching cycle to works only for 2 languages in Windows 8.1 and newer

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I use 4 input languages (English, Russian, German and Thai). But German and Thai are used only a couple of times per day. In Windows 7 it was nice solution how to organize comfortable switching between languages - it was possible to keep only 2 input languages, and make 2 more as alternate keyboard layouts. So ctrl+shift was working as switch only between English-Russian (which i am using all the time), and other hotkey combination was switcher to German/Thai. When i tried to make the same trick on Windows 8.1 i found that now i can choose keyboard layouts only from variety for input language (for example - English input language let me choose only layouts like USA/UK/Sweden/India - i can't choose layout from Chinese or Spanish).
How to add input language layouts from other languages? Or is it any other nice solution how to bind different languages pairs to different hotkeys? Or just exclude couple of languages from switching cycle, and switch to them in another way?

Comment: Consider looking over the ["Style guide for questions and answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) to ensure you understand how to write the best Q&A you can.

Comment: I also have four input languages, and I use direct shortcuts instead of `Alt`+`Shift` (e.g. `Ctrl`+`1` switches to English, `Ctrl`+`2` switches to Hebrew, etc.). You can set those in the language bar hot keys settings. `Alt`+`Shift` will still cycle through all the languages, though.